# Using Dapps with Mist / Parity

Tags: mist, dapps, parity

on http://dapps.ethercasts.com/ there are so many dapps. I want to use them. How can I do?

Tried it with geth/mist. Since geth does never completely sync, I use it as --light. Then start Mist, the browser. But mostly when I paste the url of a dapp, it loads, but the screen remains white.

As I use ubuntu I have no metamask. And chrome / chromium is trouble to make run.

Can I use parity to access dapps?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use parity to access dapps?

Yes, you can.

Click on Applications and enter your Dapp's URL

[image]

Then use the Dapp as you normally would. You can change your identity by click on the icon in the bottom right corner of your screen.
[image]

Comment: Cool! Thank you! This is helpful. Parity is awesome!

Do you recommened any dapp to try out?

Comment: Great I'm happy it is helpful. Don't forget to upvote and accept if this helps you.

Comment: http://etherplay.io/ is a cool Dapp, you play games and can earn ether if you get high scores.

Answer (score 0):

As to your second question: Yes, you can absolutely use parity to access dapps. 
I prefer to use parity with the ethereum wallet. Just start parity with the "--geth" parameter. Now you can start the Etherem Wallet App as normal and it should immediately recognize parity as your ethereum node.

Regarding your first question, I am afraid this website is not standardized. So you will need to follow the links and find out what they tell you. Either they provide an app for you to use or you need the contracts Address+ABI-Interface. Once you have those two, you can add the smart contract by selecting "Watch Contract" in the Ethereum Wallet and enter these two pieces of information.